# MongoDB executes queries sequentially instead of in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, stress-testing

I have an API endpoint which I am trying to stress test which reads a very large `MongoDB` database collection (2 million documents). Each query takes roughly **2 seconds** however the problem I am having is that the connection to the database isn't being pooled correctly so each query runs **sequentially** instead of **concurrently**.

I am using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to connect to my database and I am using [artillery.io](https://artillery.io/) for testing.

Here is my connection code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const connectionString = process.env.MONGO_DB || 'mongodb://localhost/mydatabase';

mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
    server: { poolSize: 10 }
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error: '));

db.once('open', function() {
    console.log('Connected to: ' + connectionString);
});

module.exports = db;
```

It's your pretty bog standard connection procedure however probably the most important part is the `server: { poolSize: 10 }` line.

I am using the following script for **artillery.io** testing:

```
config:
  target: 'http://localhost:1337'
  phases:
    -
      duration: 10
      arrivalRate: 5
      name: "Warm-up"

scenarios:
  -
    name: "Search by postcodes"
    flow:
      -
        post:
          url: "/api/postcodes/gb_full/search"
          headers:
            Content-Type: 'application/json'
          json:
            postcodes:
              - ABC 123,
              - DEF 345,
              - GHI 678
```

This test executes **50** calls to the API over **10 seconds**. Now here's where the problem is, the API appears to execute queries **sequentially**, see the test results below:

```
"latency": {
  "min": 1394.1,
  "max": 57693,
  "median": 30222.7,
  "p95": 55396.8,
  "p99": 57693
},
```

And the database logs are as follows:

```
connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60770 #1 (1 connection now open)
...
2017-04-10T18:45:55.389+0100 ... 1329ms
2017-04-10T18:45:56.711+0100 ... 1321ms
2017-04-10T18:45:58.016+0100 ... 1304ms
2017-04-10T18:45:59.355+0100 ... 1338ms
2017-04-10T18:46:00.651+0100 ... 1295ms
```

It appears as though the API is only using one connection, which seems correct however it was my understanding that this will automatically put the `poolSize` to good use and execute these queries **concurrently** instead of one at a time.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I execute these database queries in parallel?

---

**Edit 1** - Model and Query

To hopefully make things a little clearer, I am using the following model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = require('...');

const postcodeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    postcode: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
    location: {
      type: { type: String, required: true },
      coordinates: [] //coordinates must be in longitude, latitude order.
    }
});

//Define the index for the location object.
postcodeSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});

//Export a function that will allow us to define the collection
//name so we'll pass in something like: GB, IT, DE ect for different data sets.
module.exports = function(collectionName) {
    return db.model('Postcode', postcodeSchema, collectionName.toLowerCase());
};
```

Where the `db` object is the connection module explained at the top of this question.

And I am executing a query using the following:

```
/**
 * Searches and returns GeoJSON data for a given array of postcodes.
 * @param {Array} postcodes - The postcode array to search.
 * @param {String} collection - The name of the collection to search, i.e 'GB'.
 */
function search(postcodes, collection) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let col = new PostcodeCollection(collection.toLowerCase());

        col.find({
            postcode: { $in: postcodes }
        })
        .exec((err, docs) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);

            resolve(docs);
        });
    });
}
```

And here is an example of how the function can be called:

```
search(['ABC 123', 'DEF 456', 'GHI 789'], 'gb_full')
.then(postcodes => {
    console.log(postcodes);
})
.catch(...);
```

To re-iterate, these queries are executed via the `node.js` API, therefore they should *already* be asynchronous however the queries themselves are being executed one after the other. Therefore I believe the problem may be on the MongoDB side but I have no idea where to even start looking. It's almost as if MongoDB is blocking any other queries from being executed against the collection if there is already one running.

I am running an instance of `mongod.exe` locally on a **Windows 10** machine.

Comment: On the MongoDB side, do you have an index for your query search condition? Your response time on the database should be much smaller, take a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/ "here").

Comment: Yes, I have a geo-spatial index however in this scenario it would have no effect because I'm searching by postcode, which is not indexed. Please see the edit on my question.

Comment: I added an index on the Postcode field and now it's supremely faster, thanks for the tip. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to figure out what the issues were.

Firstly, MongoDB has a **read lock** when a query is issued (see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/)). That's why it was executing queries sequentially. The only way to improve this further is by **sharding** the collection.

Also, as Jorge suggested, I added an index on the **postcode** field and this massively reduced the latency.

```
postcodeSchema.index({ postcode: 1 }); //, { unique: true } is a tiny bit faster.
```

To put it into perspective, here are the results of the stress test with the new index in place:

```
"latency": {
  "min": 5.2,
  "max": 72.2,
  "median": 11.1,
  "p95": 17,
  "p99": null
},
```

The median latency has dropped from **30 seconds** to **11 milliseconds** which is an astonishing improvement.

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly, MongoDB has a read lock when a query is issued (see here). That's why it was executing queries sequentially. The only way to improve this further is by sharding the collection.

If you are using mongo 3.0+ with wiredtiger as the storage engine you have document level locking. The queries should not execute sequentially, the sharding would definitely help with the paralelism but 2kk docs should not be a problem for most modern computer/server hardware.

You mention the log file of mongodb on the first question, you should have more than one connection opened, is that the case?

Comment: Sorry for posting another answer, instead of a comment, i don't have the rep yet to do that yet, :/

Comment: Yes, it seems to be behaving itself by making use of pools. However even pooling wouldn't make a difference in this scenario because of the lock on the collection, so even if 10 pool users are trying to run a query it will only ever do it one at a time. I'll look into wiredtiger and sharding, thanks for your help. +1